# WordPress user search form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am wanting to make a form using the following to validate if a user exists in WordPress.

Here is what I have for the HTML page:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Is it legit?</title>
  </head>
  <p><body>
    <h3>Search by email</h3>
    <p>Input the email address to verify membership.</p>
    <form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform">
      <input  type="text" name="name">
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
</p>
```

I then want the output to be either:

```html
if ( $exists )
      echo "Yes! (their email) is a member!";
      else
      echo "No! (their email) is NOT a member!";
```

Which, based off of other searches I found this (requires email to be inputted into the code itself:

```html
<?php
  require_once("wp-load.php");

  $email = 'myemail@example.com';
  $exists = email_exists($email);
  if ( $exists )
  echo "Member exists";
  else
  echo "Member does not exist";
  ?>
```

So, how do I go about combining the two? Would I put the PHP code addressed in the 3rd example into search.php which is used from the HTML page addressed in the 1st example?

Comment: Does this form exist on the WordPress site, or outside the WordPress site? I'd recommend that it DOES exist within WordPress, in which case all of this becomes easy.  And - you mention search.php - where is that file? Is that a WordPress theme file, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find complete details understanding and using wordpress built in function
`email_exists` to check, either an email address is registered or not.
If registered, it will return the `id` of that registered email.
If not, it will return `false`.

`email_exists` complete details can be found [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/email_exists).

No, it is not necessary to hard code email in your php file to compare it with user inputted `email`.
You've to receive user inputted value into your `search.php` file.

```
$email = $_POST['name'];
```

Your code will be looked like this.

```
 <?php
      require_once("wp-load.php");

      $email = $_POST['name']; //Receiving and assigning user inputted value into $email.
      $exists = email_exists($email);
      if ( $exists )
        echo "Yes! $email  is a member!";
      else
        echo "No! $email is NOT a member!";
    ?>
```

**Suggestion:**
For security purpose, use input `type = email` for search box in your html file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put the PHP code to search the emails in the search.php file. This file will be executed when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that's what you want.

```
<?php
  require_once("wp-load.php");

  $email = addslashes($_POST['name']); //Since the form input name is name
  $exists = email_exists($email);
  if ( $exists )
  echo "Yes! $email  is a member!";
  else
  echo "No! $email is NOT a member!";
  ?>
```